# Windows SDK won't get installed

Tags: windows, sdk

I have been struggling to install Windows Software Development Kit for Windows 7 for the last day with no luck. I believe this is needed for the`<stddef.h>` header file to be found and compiled (as mentioned here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14539616/2736559)).

After downloading and running the setup, just after couple of seconds it fails. There is also a log file which [can be viewed here](http://pastebin.com/z9LM4McW). I tried looking at it so that I can get a clue what is going wrong and preventing the installation procedure. No luck yet.

How can I get this installed? Is there any kind of catch for installing SDK? any prerequisite I am not aware of?

Comment: No, that is a CRT header, it comes along with the compiler install.

Comment: I am using QtCreator 5.2 alongside VS 2012, it says it cant find that file! when i searched the net they said, its because you need platform sdk to be installed !!!

Comment: atually 3 header files cant be found, <comdef.h> <atlbase.h> and <stddef.h>. in Qtcreator i get : error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlbase.h': No such file or directoryand the likes. which i believe a VC compiler error.! 
I am told they are gone by installing a platform sdk!

Comment: Have you searched your hard disk to see if the files are there? This sounds like an include path issue, not an SDK issue.

Comment: @KenWhite: How could it be that while all 3 visual studio 2012 ,2013 and also 2010 are installed - fully!i also managed to install WDK. I have no idea where it stem from!:-/

Comment: Because `stddef.h` and `comdef.h` are part of the standard Visual C installation, and not part of the SDK. I'll ask yet again: *Have you searched your hard disk to see if the files are there?*

Comment: Yes, i did search, and they are all available!!!as shown here: http://i44.tinypic.com/2lt339j.jpg
Still dont know why i am facing this issue :-/