# QtQreator 5.2 won't compile any project and gives C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, qt5

I installed Qt5.2 msvc2012 version on my system, and after couple of failed tries to compile my projects - which were coded in the mingw version on windows (actually the Android package one) - I tried to create a new gui project and see if that works.

No surprise it didn't work and gave me the error:

> F:\ms\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2012\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:46: error:
>   C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

I searched a lot of places but couldn't figure out what was causing this problem. I even uninstalled the mingw version completely `(5.2.0-android-x86-win32-offline.exe)` still no luck.

I had Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013 installed on my system when I went for installing qt5.2, the mingw version worked fine till when I had to switch to msvc for my project. I tried installing `5.2.0-msvc2012-x86-offline.exe` and noticed it needs Visual Studio 2012 in order to compile, so I went and installed Visual Studio 2012.

After that I am getting such error plus several ones [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785007/windows-sdk-wont-get-installed?noredirect=1#comment31163737_20785007). I even tried installing WDK and WSDK but it's not working. The path I believe is configured correctly and files do exist. This is my include path in environmental variable on windows 7sp1 x86

```
J:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE;J:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\include\shared;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\include\winrt;
```

What is wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It was enough for me (with same problem) to add `$(VC_IncludePath)` and `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)` as Imclude path in project configuration